# How to make a file "searchable" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Thought this would be a good SO question since couldn't find anything on Google and figured someone out there might know the quick answer.

I have the fantastic utility *Pixie*, it's basically an .exe sitting in my Program Files.  It wasn't an official install, simply downloaded and placed it there.

Rather than navigate to it to run, and rather not clutter my desktop with links, I would love to take advantage of Windows 7 great integrated Search functionality.  The problem is, Search doesn't return anything for "Pixie", I think there must be some index somewhere on the computer, and that index gets updated with official installs, etc.

How can I get simple exe files recognized with Windows 7 Search?

Comment: I believe this question might be more appropriate on SuperUser.

Comment: indyK1ng, you are probably right, SO is a force of habit though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you not add a shortcut to Pixie in the folder of shortcuts which contains your 'programs list'

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

I guess then it will find the shortcut :)

Comment: Thanks Stafanvds, I thought about putting it in the Start menu as well, but then thought that might be a bit intrusive, but now that you mention the Programs that's not bad.

I like this solution, I'm still curious if there is a way to add to the Search without doing this, but not bad at all.

Comment: This also works for Windows 8! Just copy your shortcut to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Answer (score 1):

Start / Indexing Options should help in adding custom locations to the search index.

Answer (score 1):

There is a user-specific folder which contains items that appear in the windows-10 start menu.

```
C:\Users\jaroslav\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

you may want to use

```
%appdata%
```

which usually points to `C:\Users\jaroslav\AppData` on this system

protip: remove "- shortcut" from whatever you put in there *before* moving.

Answer (score 0):

One of my most-used utility programs is called Everything. It will quickly find anything on your computer. Just key in any part/portion of the filename (maybe using format xpixx.exe) and . . . you will be very impressed. Google the program and download it for free (tho' I've willingly made a donation). Just remember that if you change any filenames, you won't find them unless you relaunch Everything. Best. (Subseq edit; re specimen search . . for x read the star key)